# Installing Visual Studio 2008 besides Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, installation

I got Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on my machine.

Now i require to install Visual Studio 2008 besdies VS2010 as need to work on a project which builds custom component for SSIS.

I cannot use VS2010 for this because of DTS reference libraries.

Can i install VS2008 without any conflicts with VS2010

Comment: I have them both installed on my work machine, never had a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Visual Studio Versions Side-by-Side 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: However, note the warning on the 2010 version of that page: ["We recommend that you install Visual Studio versions in the order in which they were released. For example, install Visual Studio 2008 before you install Visual Studio 2010."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609(v=VS.100).aspx)